# How to display the single image on the mobile device in owl-carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel-2

I am using an owl-carousel plugin for slide the image. After the page load, I am displaying the four images at a time then it will side one by one on click or auto.

I am getting the issue on the mobile device. In the mobile device, I am getting the four images. I need, it should be display two or one image.

Would you help me out in this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 1000,
    paginationSpeed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    items: 4,
    itemsDesktop: false,
    itemsDesktopSmall: false,
    itemsTablet: false,
    itemsMobile: false,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"]
  });

});
```

```css
#owl-example {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

body .owl-nav {
  position: initial;
}

body .owl-nav div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  /*border:1px solid #000;*/
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  background-color: #0065B3 !important;
}

body .owl-prev {
  left: -20px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
}

body .owl-next {
  right: -20px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
}

body .owl-prev i,
body .owl-next i {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

body #owl-example .owl-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #f6f1f1;
}

body #owl-example .owl-item:last-child {
  padding: 0;
}

body .owl-dots {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 384px) {
  body #owl-example .owl-item {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--content slider-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container">

    <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>

      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: my answer is right

Comment: check with your own code https://jsfiddle.net/se0etqew/8/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `responsive` option of the `owl carousel` to set the items in different break points.

```
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1,
        nav:true
    },
    600:{
        items:3,
        nav:false
    },
    1000:{
        items:4,
        nav:true,
        loop:false
    }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 1000,
    paginationSpeed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    items: 4,
    itemsDesktop: false,
    itemsDesktopSmall: false,
    itemsTablet: false,
    itemsMobile: false,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"],
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        nav: true
      },
      600: {
        items: 3,
        nav: false
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#owl-example {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

body .owl-nav {
  position: initial;
}

body .owl-nav div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  /*border:1px solid #000;*/
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  background-color: #0065B3 !important;
}

body .owl-prev {
  left: -20px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
}

body .owl-next {
  right: -20px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
}

body .owl-prev i,
body .owl-next i {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

body #owl-example .owl-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #f6f1f1;
}

body #owl-example .owl-item:last-child {
  padding: 0;
}

body .owl-dots {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 384px) {
  body #owl-example .owl-item {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--content slider-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container">

    <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>

      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>
      <div class="owl_text"><img src="https://blogs.colum.edu/demomagazine/files/2014/09/demo.png" class="img_size"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

- [*Reference Documentation*](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add responsive property in this function like

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
responsiveClass:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1,
        nav:true
    },
    600:{
        items:3,
        nav:false
    },
    1000:{
        items:5,
        nav:true,
        loop:false
    }
}
})
```

Comment: I've removed your upvote, for the same reasons as my other comment in the other answer. You should try to help the site by becoming more tidy with answers, and upvoting those answers that deserve, rather than adding your own just to try and get points.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 1000,
      paginationSpeed : 1000,
      autoplay:true,
      items : 4, 
      itemsDesktop : false,
      itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      itemsTablet: false,
      itemsMobile : false,
      loop:true,
      nav:true,
      navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>","<i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"],
      responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: you need just change just items value whatever you want to show box accordingly its width....

Comment: didn't downvote....but one question why you posted a same answer if there are already two same answer...if you found other answer correct you can upvote them rather than posting the same answer

Comment: I made addition same code it does not mean I copied the code what they answer the post

Comment: I didn't say that you copied the code but somewhere the answer is same...I think you will understand...rest is up to you...

Comment: @Bhuwan is absolutely right. You cannot just add your own answer if there's an existing answer, the idea is to vote the correct answer up, regardless of who created it. What you've done is actually even more unhelpful to the OP. The only difference to yours, is that you've used the OP's full code in their question, which you've copied and pasted, adding the new code from someone elses answer. You should delete your answer.